# What does the adb command do WITHIN an Android device's shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I was connected to my Android device's shell (by doing `adb shell` in my computer's shell) and without realizing, I typed `adb devices`. Instead of giving me a `command not found` error or something, it actually listed one device! The output:

```
 $ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
```

Why does my phone have an adb command, and what is the emulator device?

EDIT: I tried it again and it still works, though now the list of devices it gives is empty. The only difference between when I did it just now and when I did it before is that before, I was doing the bridge [wirelessly](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless) and now I'm doing it through a wired connection. I know that it's not running the `adb` command on my computer, because in both cases when I run it on my computer I get a different output.

Comment: are you really sure that you an `adb shell` session was running? did you try it again?

Answer (score 1):

Some phones do include the `adb` binary. Some for a specific purpose, others just because the manufacturer was too lazy to edit the default `makefile`.

Also `adb devices` listing an offline instance of an "emulator" does not mean that there's an emulator running on the device, just that there is an open tcp port in the range that `adb` scans when looking for emulator instances. Just ignore it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about emulator.Emulator creates a virtual android device. By using this facility a programmer can test his code on computer without connecting any device.
You can read about emulator from [https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator)

Comment: Right, but it seems to be saying that this emulator is runnning on the *phone*...