# How can i remove orphan device from "adb devices"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

I'm currently having trouble with ADB.
When I type "adb devices" it shows:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
```

I deleted all my AVDs and I have no phones connected to the computer.
If I run "adb usb" or "adb tcpip 5554" it sais:

```
error: device offline
```

I've tried rebooting my pc, "adb kill-server", reinstalled Android Studio, but nothing worked.

Thank you

Comment: Use `nmap` or something to see if you have anything listening on port 5554 or 5555 on `localhost`. Perhaps `adb` is seeing some other software that you have running and is getting confused.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was using MONyog and it was blocking port 5555. I used this tool to see which ports are bing blocked: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37995582/1778421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using MONyog and it was blocking port 5555. I used this tool to see which ports are bing blocked: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx